# The set of all positive values of $a$ for which the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ((1/n) - \tan^{-1}(1/n))^a$ converges

Tags: real-analysis

> The set of all positive values of $a$ for which the series
>
> $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty ((1/n) - \tan^{-1}(1/n))^a$$
>
> converges, is
>
> (A) $(0,1/3]$
> (B) $(0,1/3)$
> (C) $[1/3,\infty)$
> (D) $(1/3,\infty)$

How can I solve this problem? I am totally helpless. Thanks for your help  .

Answer (score 3):

$$\arctan \frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{3x^3}+\frac{1}{5x^5}-\cdots $$

Which yields $$\frac{1}{n}-\arctan \frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{3n^3}-\frac{1}{5n^5}+\frac{1}{7n^7}-\cdots$$

Hence deduce that: $$\left(\frac{1}{3n^3}-\frac{1}{5n^5}\right)^a<\left(\frac{1}{n}-\arctan \frac{1}{n}\right)^a<\left(\frac{1}{3n^{3}}\right)^a$$

From this it is clear that we only have convergence for $a>\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x-\arctan{x} \sim x^3/3$  for small $x$.  Then use the comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$\tan^{-1}x=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\cdots$$
at $x=0$, we get
$$\frac{1}{n}-\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{3n^3}-\frac{1}{5n^5}+\cdots$$
By limit comparison test, $\sum \left( \frac{1}{n}-\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{n} \right)^a$ converges if $a>1/3$, and diverges if $a\le 1/3$.